# What is the most efficient way to select from MYSQL database where the condition on a coloumn which has NULL, one userId or list of userIds

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization

I have a table which has userId and their one attribute which has long text. as follow,

[image: database]

The table contains about 2 millions of rows and need to select rows for given userId (and all the rows with userId is NULL). Since there are  three kinds of rows which has UserId is NULL, UserId has only one value and UserId has several UserIds separated by '/'. (I know it is good to separate that values and normalizing the table is good but this is the requirement.)
So my question is what is the suitable method to retrieve the rows. Now i have implemented two methods,

1. `"SELECT *  FROM user WHERE userId LIKE  '%" + userId + "%' OR userId is null"`
2. seperate the rows which userId has list of values into another table and retrive rows from first table using  `"SELECT *  FROM user1 WHERE userId =  '" + userId + "' OR userId is NULL"` and then retrive rows from second table using like query (`"SELECT *  FROM user2 WHERE userId LIKE  '%" + userId + "%'"`)

Bot methods have same efficiency.So are there any other way to do that? Or else are there any improvements to these methods?

Comment: Never ever store data like that (/ separated items.)... It will only cause you lots of trouble. Use integer for id's, and one value per row!

Comment: I can only suggest you take a look at [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) since what you currently have is a bad design. If you solve that then your problem you currently experience is solved as well. So: Create a new table that has a FK to the user and another FK to your data (params?) and use that (newly created) table to select your desired results using joins. Also: A `Like %...%` will *always* perform horrible (which will also be solved / unnecessary when correctly normalized).

Comment: yeah this is a bad design. I agree. since for a given param1, there can be thousands of userIds and there can be around millions of param1 entries, Our group members suggested this method. and we need to achieve 20,000 db calls for a second.

Comment: It may be a little extra work to 'refactor' your database to a decently normalized version but that will, in the long run, always beat going with what you currently have. It's better to fix this problem *now* than later (or never). You'll probably get this working anyway (it's not impossible nor hard), but performance will be horrible to begin with.

Comment: do you have an Index on Userid ? along with your storage pattern,  2 millions of rows in the table is something which has to be in counts for the performance. I think, you need to write a script to separate these multi-ID records permanently , and then create an index on the same column , OTHERWISE, your 2nd method would be more tuned with existing resources as  leading wildcard '%' won't let you use an Index.

Comment: Listen to your group members less. :-)

Comment: In addition to other comments, you could add indexes to your normalized database so that you could search by userId faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, really, insist on keeping the current table as-is and knowingly choose to not-normalize your database then all I can suggest is creating another table that "normalizes" your 'users' values for this specific query. Create a new table that holds the normalized values of what you currently store in the `UserId` field and use, for your specific query, that newly created table.

In this specific case: You can have your cake and eat it too! You can start work on database-normalizing but there's no need to drop your current `UserId` field just yet. You *will* need to make sure you keep both (the `UserId` field and your newly created table with FK's) 'in sync' but other than that you should be fine to go. You can 'slowly migrate' to using your newly created table and by the time your application(s) no longer rely on the `/`-separated `UserId` field you can drop the column by then. Meanwhile you get the benefits of your (better) normalized database for the new(er) code you're working on, including the current query.

Oh, and, ofcourse, make sure that your newly created table has correct indices to even further improve the performance of your queries.